# Cannot run event handler in .cs file from ModalPopupExtender

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I want to create a simple Yes/No popup window. So I have added a ModalPopupExtender to the .aspx page.

The popup panel's markup is:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_yes" runat="server" Text="Yes" onclick="btn_yes_Click" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
<asp:Button ID="btn_no" runat="server" Text="No" />
```

For some reason, I cannot get into the function `btn_yes_Click`, not sure why. Do I have to use Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are also setting the ModalPopupExtenders OkControlID property to "btn_yes".
As you can see in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1166869/1558010) this will cause the OnClick event not to fire.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the OKControlID Property on ModalPopupExtender tag is specified. Take a look at this topic: [The Event Handler of the OK button inside a Modal PopUp is not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733658/the-event-handler-of-the-ok-button-inside-a-modal-popup-is-not-executing/21383578)